# Custom Lwc in Flow not returning value, summer 20

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, bug

I am using custom lwc to capture data about selected checkboxes inside flow. It was working properly until summer 20 release. Now it does not return any value.

```
@api
get result() {
    return this.value.join(';');
}
```

I have checked and value is updated properly. However it seems that getter for result is only called on load of the component and it always returns empty string. Assigning output values to variables does not work, neither does accessing result directly. How can i ensure that the getter will be called?

Comment: Seems likely you need to generate a flow attribute change event, similar to those shown in the [documentation example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation).

Comment: @PhilW This would allow me to get the value in my lwc but I need to set it in the Flow. If regular FlowEvent does not call the getter I have some doubts that calling the same event from Lwc will result in different behaviour

Comment: The point is that the event should inform the runtime that the property has changed, so the flow can accept the updated value. I recommend you give it a try.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Everything was working properly from Lwc. Dispaching an event resulted in update in getter. But this value was not passed into flow. It seems that I must change something inside flow to call this getter but so far nothing works

Comment: If you can provide more detail on the flow, especially around where the property value is supposed to then get populated into a flow variable, that would help.

Comment: We have the same issue today after org dev/scratch orgs updated to Summer 20. the "FlowAttributeChangeEvent" does not work either after the upgrade.

Comment: My team (Salesforce) is looking into similar issues with LWCs in flows right now. Would you mind sharing the code from your LWC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have also been struggle with this issue for today. I have two lwc components embedded in lightning flow. Both of them use "FlowAttributeChangeEvent" to communicate value back to the flow. After update to summer 20 on my scratch org both of them do not updated output attribute correctly. I fixed one of them by increase lwc api version from 47.0 to 49.0. However for the other one I still face the issue that property does not get update and here is the flow config:
 [image: lightning flow config for lwc component]

What I found is that if I change "Set component visibilty" to always visible then my attribute almost always populated with the "FlowAttributeChangeEvent". If I have set the "Set component visibilty" with conditions it seems like the flow failed on retrieving values from "FlowAttributeChangeEvent". I feel this is a salesforce bug on their flow after the upgrade. But I cannot find any issue logged on community about this behaviour.

My walk around for now is to stop use "Set component visibilty" and use decision is  route between two screens and one of the screen always have the lwc component show.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same issue today. Finally solved it by firing the FlowAttributeChangeEvent but outside the getter...before firing my FlowNavigationNextEvent.

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary dispatch a event,

````
    this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('result', this.result));```
````